# Deleting records from Oracle MAX_PARTITION

Tags: oracle, partitioning

We have a table with partitions. It also has an overflow partition (max partition) which sorts of acts as a catch-all for records which do not match the partition criteria. The idea was to create the partitions ahead of time so the records never end up in the max_partition. However for one table, this was missed out, so all the records ended up in that single partition.

Now most of these records are not used anymore so they can be deleted. However our approach is to drop the partitions when its too old. This cannot be done in this case. Is there an easy way to handle the purge?

Maybe its an idea to create the partitions now and move the records to them and then drop the partition now, but however it seems like its going to be very poor in performance. The other option was to create a temp table where a subset of records are moved and deleted from there, but again moving the records individually seems time consuming. This table has around 5 million records.

Which would be the best way forward, performance wise. We could manage a little downtime but not much.

We use Oracle 11g.

The table creation script looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "TRANSACTIONS" 
   ("year" number(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE)
  PARTITION BY RANGE ("year") 
 (PARTITION "P_OLD" VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
  PARTITION "P_2011"   VALUES LESS THAN (2011),
 ...

  PARTITION "P_MAX"    VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to drop the partition, you can purge it.

```
alter table TRANSACTIONS TRUNCATE PARTITION P_MAX UPDATE INDEXES;
```

or if you prefer, you can also delete the rows:

```
delete from TRANSACTIONS PARTITION (P_MAX);
```

You may use INTERVAL partition to make it simpler (actually I don't understand your question):

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS ( 
   ...
    TRANSACTION_DATE TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL
)    
PARTITION BY RANGE (TRANSACTION_DATE) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '12' MONTH) 
    (PARTITION P_OLD VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00' ) )
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
```

Comment: I still need to retain latest records. I only need to purge the older records which should have ideally gone into the other partitions, if they existed. For example data from P_2011 and P_2012 etc should be purged while data for last 3 years should be retained.

Comment: Then replace `P_MAX` by `P_2011` - where is the problem?

Comment: to clarify we should have created P_year partitions but we didn't and all records ended up in P_MAX. Now we expect P_YEAR to be present for all records for last 3 years and rest purged. Eventually all new records should end up in P_YEAR partitions and P_MAX should remain empty.

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed possible to create interval partition. Now since this table is already present would creating partition now have impact? Especially around re-building indexes?

Comment: Adding a new (empty) partition does not take any time. Rebuilding the index may take some time.